# Integer canno be derefrenced

Tags: java, variables

I have some problem with my simple code in Java. I want to do aircraft flight search program, but when I leave the variable under the parameter, I get an error:

```
Airlines.java:14: error: int cannot be dereferenced
    String Parameters = flightNumber_go.getParameters();
```

Anyone have any idea how I could solve this problem?

PS. Sorry for my bad English

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Airlines{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        Flight 524 = new Flight("Moskwa", "Londyn", 140);
        Flight 135 = new Flight("Warszawa", "Wroclaw", 60);
        Flight 141 = new Flight("Frankfurt", "Rzym", 95);

        Scanner flightNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter code of your flight: ");
        int flightNumber_go = Integer.valueOf(flightNumber.nextLine());

        String Parameters = flightNumber_go.getParameters();
        System.out.println(Parameters);

    }
}

class Flight{
    String departures;
    String arrival;
    int price;

    public Flight(String departures, String arrival, int price){
        this.departures = departures;
        this.arrival = arrival;
        this.price = price;
    }
    public String getParameters(String ... args){
        return "Lot z "+this.departures+" do "+this.arrival+" kosztuje "+this.price;
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you expect `flightNumber_go.getParameters()` to do, bearing in mind that `flightNumber_go` is an `int`? Did you mean to declare it as a `Flight` instead, and construct a new instance of `Flight`?

Comment: also, reading up on naming conventions would make your code a lot easier to read

Comment: `Flight 524 = new Flight(...` you cannot name variables this way. Variable name must start from letter or underscore (`_`)

Comment: ok, great, but can someone show me how to do this?

Comment: I think he I understand what he _thinks_ this code is doing.  He thinks if puts `flightNumber_go` as `524`, `getParameters` will look for the `Flight` with that number.  Thats not what your code does however, and if you want to look up the number you should put your `Flight`s in a `Collection` such as `ArrayList`.

Comment: Thank Nexevis, i think that i can do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To begin with you are misunderstanding how to correctly use an `Object` as `getParameters` will only work for the *current* object, it will not search all the objects you made.  You must use a `Collection` to keep track on all of your objects if you want to find a specific one.

Additionally you should not use variable *names* to store information, instead store that information inside of the object as an integer.

Here is the modified `Flight` class:

```
class Flight {
    private String departures;
    private String arrival;
    private int price;
    private int flightNum;

    public Flight(String departures, String arrival, int price, int flightNum){
        this.departures = departures;
        this.arrival = arrival;
        this.price = price;
        this.flightNum = flightNum;
    }
    public String getParameters(){
        return "Lot z "+this.departures+" do "+this.arrival+" kosztuje "+this.price;
   }
    public String getDepartures() {
        return departures;
    }
    public String getArrival() {
        return arrival;
    }
    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }
    public int getFlightNum() {
        return flightNum;
    }
    public void setDepartures(String departures) {
        this.departures = departures;
    }
    public void setArrival(String arrival) {
        this.arrival = arrival;
    }
    public void setPrice(int price) {
        this.price = price;
    }
    public void setFlightNum(int flightNum) {
        this.flightNum = flightNum;
    }

}
```

Note that I added the new parameter, `flightNum` and made all of your class variables `private`, with standard getters and setters for access.

Now here is the modified `Airlines` class that uses an `ArrayList` to store the `Flight`s:

```
class Airlines {
    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception{
        ArrayList<Flight> flights = new ArrayList<>();
        flights.add(new Flight("Moskwa", "Londyn", 140, 524));
        flights.add(new Flight("Warszawa", "Wroclaw", 60, 135));
        flights.add(new Flight("Frankfurt", "Rzym", 95, 141));

        Scanner flightNumber = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter code of your flight: ");
        int flightNumber_go = Integer.valueOf(flightNumber.nextLine());
        Flight currentFlight = findFlight(flights, flightNumber_go);
        System.out.println(currentFlight.getParameters());

    }

    public static Flight findFlight(ArrayList<Flight> flights, int flightNum) {
        for (Flight f : flights) {
            if (f.getFlightNum() == flightNum) {
                return f;
            }
        }
        //If no flights are found
        return null;
   }
}
```

I added a `static` method called `findFlight` which takes in the `ArrayList` and `flightNumber` you want to find as a parameter, and returns the corresponding `Flight`.  This is done using a simple enhanced `for` loop.  The method will return `null` if no flight is found, which can modified to return whatever you want for a default case.

**Example Run:**

> Enter code of your flight:
>
> 135
>
> Lot z Warszawa do Wroclaw kosztuje 60

**Note:**  It may make sense in your case to use a `Map` to store the key as the flight number with the `Flight` as the value which ensures the key is unique and then you do not need `flightNumber` in the `Object` itself.  This `ArrayList` is just one way to do it.

Comment: Thanks for your solution but I have another problem in my terminal:                                          Airlines.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        ArrayList<Flight> flights = new ArrayList<>();

Comment: Did you import `ArrayList` at the top?  `import java.util.ArrayList;`  I did not include this, I thought it was assumed.